# Is there any way to write stylesheet specific to thermal printer?

Tags: css, asp.net, media-queries, thermal-printer

I am using ASP.Net MVC.

I have a view,which I need to print. If its Laser printer then using media queries, I  can configure a print friendly version of my view.

**But how do I do the same for thermal printer.**

Is there any option, where we can write stylesheet specific to thermal printer?

Or any other way to do the same?